# Google Analytics mark a conversion from admin website

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering if there is a way to track conversions on my site. I have clients fill out a form on our site (www) which I am now tracking with an event. Our agents work those requests from our admin site (admin) and if successful, they mark it as sold. A conversion is when a requests gets marked as sold, but that is not the same analytics user (client) as the analytics user (our agent) who marks the request as sold.

Tracking events is not as precise as actual conversions. Is there a way to track this sort of transaction?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you want to assign a dollar value to a conversion if the sales person is successful.  From a technical standpoint you can't have GA automatically do this.  What you CAN do to get an accurate estimation of conversion value is by calculating the average profit per successful lead multiply it by your conversion rate from your CRM.  Historical data will be very helpful.

For example if you make $10 for each successful lead, you successfully convert %50 of your leads, then you can comfortably give the conversion a value of $5.  (IE: 10 * .5 = 5)

GA isn't really meant to be a CRM (Customer Relations Manager) and while it excels at tracking eCommerse transactions its not meant to house detailed client data.  Doing what I mentioned above will give you a great indicator of your conversion value.  You can also change this value at any time as your business changes.

EDIT after comment was added:

...deleted...

Triple edit:
Using GA in a manner that can directly identify a user is in violation of their TOS.  I wrote out how to do it and then reviewed the TOS.  Not only is this bad practice but it will get you kicked out of GA.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to turn the event of filling our a form request into a true conversion. The event of filling our a request is NOT a conversion. Only if a sales person works that request can it turn into a conversion. I am looking for a way to identify the event of filling out the form and turning it into a conversion at a later time. I can count the "form event" and figure our close ratio and apply that ratio to the "form event" and guestimate the conversions from the "form events". I was hoping there was some sort of API where I could mark this event as a conversion.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect this new comment.